# Prove Aut(G) of Sym(G) is bijective

Tags: group-theory

I know that Aut(G) is defined as the set of all isomorphisms from a group G to itself. But I've also seen another supposedly equivalent definition that states:

Aut(G) = {f in Sym(G) | f(g1g2) = f(g1)*f(g2)}, where * denotes permutation composition.

The above definition is the definition for a group homomorphism, how can I prove that any element in Aut(G) is also bijective?

Comment: That definition specifies $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ a subset of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$, which consists of bijections.

Comment: Well then why isn't Aut(G) = Sym(G)? I mean, if Sym(G) is a set of isomorphisms, then elements in Sym(G) would surely be group homomorphisms, which must satisfy the condition f(g1g2) = f(g1)*f(g2)?

Comment: No, Sym(G) is just the set of set bijections on $G$. They form a group under function composition, but there is no requirement that they be group homomorphisms. The ones that happen to actually be group morphisms are Aut(G).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element in $\;Sym(G)\;$ is bijective, but *not necessarily* a **homomorphism**. Thus, as any automorphism is, in particular, a bijection (as it is **an isomorphism** , as you wrote, and then injective and surjective), we have Aut$\,(G)\subset Sym\,(G)\;$ , which means precisely that: any automorphism of $\;G\;$ is trivially (by definition)  a bijection.

Comment: But isn't an isomorphism a bijective homomorphism? So let's say f is an isomorphism from G to G, then f is a bijective homomorphism from G to G? Unless homomorphism is a stronger condition than isomorphism in groups?

Comment: Maybe isomorphism only means a bijection in groups, whereas homomorphism is a rather unrelated condition.

Comment: @W.Scott Yes, an isom. is a bijective hom. ...

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $f\in\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ if

- it is a function $f:G\to G$
- $f$ is bijective

By definition, $f\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ if

- it is a function $f:G\to G$
- $f$ is bijective
- $f$ is a group homomorphism

Therefore $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ consists of all elements of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ which are group homomorphisms. Which is exactly what the cited definition states.

Answer (score 1):

To address the followup question in the comments, regarding whether $\text{Aut}(G)=\text{Sym(G)}$, let's take the example of the group $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ represented as $G=\{0,1,2\}$ with addition modulo 3, so for example $2+2=1$ in $G$.

Consider the following element of $\text{Sym}(G)$:
$$f(0) = 1, \,\, f(1) = 2 \,\, f(2)=0
$$

Is $f \in \text{Aut}(G)$? Well... no it isn't:
$$f(1+1)=f(2)=0 \,\,\text{but}\,\, f(1) + f(1) = 2+2 = 1 \ne 0
$$

Comment: Thanks! Basically, A group isomorphism is a bijection which may or may not be a group homomorphism?

Comment: No, a group isomorphism is a bijection which IS a group homomorphism.